# Error with Flowable's onErrorResumeNext, networkOnMainThread

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have the following rxJava chain:

```
 override fun combineLocationToPlace(req: Flowable<Place>): Flowable<Place> {
        var combinedFlowable = Flowable
                .combineLatest(
                        req,
                        getLastLocation().lastOrError().toFlowable(),
                        BiFunction<Place, Location, Place> { t1, location ->
                            Timber.w("FIRSTINIT - Retrieved location $location")
                            var placeLocation = Location(t1.placeName)
                            placeLocation.latitude = t1.latitude
                            placeLocation.longitude = t1.longitude
                            t1.distance = location.distanceTo(placeLocation)
                            t1
                        })


        return combinedFlowable
                .onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable ->
                    Timber.w(t, "FIRSTINIT - Could not retrieve location for place (${t.message}) returning original request")
                    req
                }
                .doOnError {
                    Timber.w("FIRSTINIT - did detect the error here...")
                }

        return combinedFlowable
    }
```

In short, I am retrieving some data from the local database (a place) and I want to combine it with the latest location from the GPS:

```
 override fun getLastLocation(requestIfEmpty: Boolean): Observable<Location> {
        var lastLocation = locationProvider.lastKnownLocation
                .doOnNext {
                    Timber.w("Got location $it from last one")
                }
                .doOnComplete {
                    Timber.w("did i get a location?")
                }

        if (requestIfEmpty) {
            Timber.w("Switching to request of location")
            lastLocation = lastLocation.switchIfEmpty(requestLocation())
        }

        return lastLocation.doOnNext {
            Timber.w("Got something!")
            location = it
        }


    }
```

But I want to account for the scneario where the user does not have a last location, and thus the line:

```
return combinedFlowable
                    .onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable ->
                        Timber.w(t, "FIRSTINIT - Could not retrieve location for place (${t.message}) returning original request")
                        req
                    }
                    .doOnError {
                        Timber.w("FIRSTINIT - did detect the error here...")
                    }
```

Which is trying to catch any error and retry just with the original request without combining it with anything. I am calling this code like this:

```
fun getPlace(placeId: String) {
        locationManager.combineLocationToPlace(placesRepository.getPlace(placeId))
                .onErrorResumeNext { t: Throwable ->
                    Timber.e(t, "Error resuming next! ")
                    placesRepository.getPlace(placeId)
                }.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()).observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                .subscribeBy(
                        onNext = {
                            place.value = Result.success(it)
                        },
                        onError = {
                            Timber.e("ERROR! $it")
                            place.value = Result.failure(it)
                        }
                )
                .addTo(disposables)

    }
```

However, when there is no location a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown, my flowable switches to the original request, and then upon executing it I get a `NetworkOnMainThread` exception. Shouldn't this request be executed on the `scheduler.io()` that I put in there (since I put the code before that)?

In case you are wondering, `schedulerProvider.io()` translates to:

```
Schedulers.io()
```

GetPlace:

```
  /**
     * Retrieves a single place from database
     */
      override fun getPlace(id: String): Flowable<Place> {
        return Flowable.merge(placesDao.getPlace(id),
                refreshPlace(id).toFlowable())
    }

    /**
     * Triggers a refreshPlace update on the db, useful when changing stuff associated with the place
     * itself indirectly (e.g. an experience)
     */
    private fun refreshPlace(id: String): Single<Place> {
        return from(placesApi.getPlace(id))
                .doOnSuccess {
                    placesDao.savePlace(it)
                }
    }
```

Comment: `onErrorResumeNext` subscribes to the fallback on the thread which signaled the error. You should apply `req.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to make sure the side-effects there happen on the right thread. As for how far an `observeOn` or `subscribeOn` reaches depends on what operators are involved and is a non-trivial task to guess correctly. Therefore, always apply `subscribeOn` and/or `observeOn` when you are in doubt.

Comment: but i am already doing that...

Comment: Which is the original request you talk about, `req`? I don't see any `req.subscribeOn`. Also if you have an error, why didn't you post the stacktrace which could shed some light about where the problem may be?

Comment: you are right, appending subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()) to the original request fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To ensure your networking happens off of the main thread send it to a background thread explicitly.

Use either the IO, New Thread or Computation schedulers from the Rx Schedulers class:

```
subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
```

For cases when you don't want to do this (or if you believe that it should already be on a background thread and just want to debug), you can log thread information as follows:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

This can be particularly useful for tracking what is going on when you are using either `Schedulers.trampoline()` of if you have different schedulers for observe and subscribe like in your example:

```
.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()).observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
```

Answer (score 4):

You cant use onErrorResumeNext to implement this funcionality. You should use retryWhen operator.

Maybe this post is usefull for you.

https://medium.com/@v.danylo/server-polling-and-retrying-failed-operations-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-8bcc7e641a5a

this code poll a server with backoff until receives a code different from 204.
Maybe you can adapt to your needs using retryWhen instead of repeatWhen.

```
  fun pollServerWithBackoff(videoId: String, maxAttempts: Int, delay: Int): Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> {
        return api.download(videoId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .repeatWhen {
                    it
                            .zipWith(Flowable.range(1, maxAttempts),
                                    BiFunction { _: Any?, attempt: Int -> attempt })
                            .flatMap {

                                Flowable.timer((it * delay).toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            }

                }
                .takeUntil({

                    it.code() != 204
                })
                .filter {

                    it.code() != 204
                }
                .map{
                    if(it.code() in 200..300)
                        it
                    else
                        throw IOException(it.errorBody()?.toString() ?: "Unkown Error")
                }
    }
```